# Prove that $(1 - \frac 1 {3^p})^{{\frac 1 p}^{ n_0(p)-1}}$ $\le$ $1 \over 4$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $p \in (0, \infty)$, $n \in \Bbb N$. Prove that there is a constant $n_0(p) \in \Bbb N$ such that for every $n \ge n_0(p)$, the inequality

$\int_0^1$ $(1 - t^p)^{n \over p}$ $dt$ $\le$ $1 \over 2$

holds.

We were given the hint to prove first that there is an $n_0(p)$ such that

$(1 - \frac 1 {3^p})^{{\frac 1 p}^{ n_0(p) - 1}}$ $\le$ $1 \over 4$.

I tried to get a feeling for this inequality by choosing a few values for $p$. The problem I encountered is that if I choose $p$ a bit larger (for example $p = 100$), the expression

$(1 - \frac 1 {3^p})$

is already extremly close to $1$. The expression $1 \over p$ is moving it even further to $1$. Therefore, I would have to choose $n_0(p)$ extremly large to move away from $1$, but I get nowhere close to $\frac 1 4$. What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you mean $$\left(1-\frac1{3^p}\right)^{1/p^{n_0(p)}}\;\;?$$

Comment: I think he meant $$\left(1 - \frac 1 {3^p}\right)^{\left({\frac 1 p}\right)^{ n_0(p)}}$$

Comment: Yes, the last one is correct, sorry, I struggled with the formatting a little bit.

Comment: Well, both are equivalent.

Comment: It's more like the exponent is of $\frac{n_0(p)}{p}$ otherwise, it's indeed getting closer to $1$.

Comment: Take $p =1,$ then you can not find such $n_0.$ I think this should be true if $p \in (1, +\infty).$

Comment: Well, for $p = 1$, one can choose $n_0(p) = 4$, which gives roughly $1 \over 5$. But this can't be done so easily when $p$ is large. At least that's what Wolfram tells me here. Take a look at the situation for $p = 100$: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1+-+1+%2F+3%5E100)%5E1%2F100

Comment: Damn, I forgot to put in the $-1$ here, corrected it.

Comment: So for $p = 1$, I would have to choose $n_0(p) = 5$ then, but the problem for large $p$ remains.

Comment: If  $p =1$ then the left hand side becomes $2/3 = (1-\frac{1}{3^1})^{\frac{1}{1^{n_0}}}$

Comment: Shouldn't $n_0(p)$ be in the numerator here? Like rtybase wrote it.

Comment: Since a^n^m = a^{n*m}

Comment: But you agreed with what ajotatexe said in the 2nd comment

Comment: I was wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is confusing (thus, *this is more of a correction suggestion* and a partial answer), because $\left(1-\frac{1}{3^p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}^{n_0(p)-1}}$ means $\left(1-\frac{1}{3^p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p^{n_0(p)-1}}}$.

Now, let's consider **the $p>1$ case**. 
$$\frac{1}{3^p}<\frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow 1-\frac{1}{3^p}>\frac{1}{2}$$
Given $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{p}}$ is ascending for $x>0$, easy to check taking the first derivative:
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{3^p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}>\frac{1}{2^{\frac{1}{p}}}$$
Given $g(x)=2^x$ is ascending and $\frac{1}{p}<1$

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{3^p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}>\frac{1}{2^{\frac{1}{p}}}>\frac{1}{2}>\frac{1}{4}$$
Now, ${\frac{1}{p^{n_0(p)-1}}}<\frac{1}{p}$ and $h(x)=\left(1-\frac{1}{3^p}\right)^x$ is descending, because $0<1-\frac{1}{3^p}<1$:
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{3^p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p^{n_0(p)-1}}}>\left(1-\frac{1}{3^p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}>\frac{1}{2^{\frac{1}{p}}}>\frac{1}{2}>\frac{1}{4}$$
As a result, for $p>1$, there is no way to make this expression less than $\frac{1}{4}$.

**I am inclined to think** that it should be $$\left(1-\frac{1}{3^p}\right)^{\frac{n_0(p)-1}{p}}$$
which is also similar to the integrand. In this case, again $p>1$, from $1>\left(1-\frac{1}{3^p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}>\frac{1}{4}$ and [knowing that for $0<a<1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_%7Bn%20%5Crightarrow%20%5Cinfty%7D%20a%5En)
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a^n=0$$
there will obviously be such an $n_0(p)$ such that $$\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{3^p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \right)^n=\left(1-\frac{1}{3^p}\right)^{\frac{n}{p}}\leq \frac{1}{4}$$
$\forall n>n_0(p)-1$.

Comment: You're right, thanks. Just wondering why this is so hard to verify with a calcuator.

Comment: No problems. I'd recommend learning e.g. Python, it's quite easy to write code to validate behaviour of various sequences, functions etc. Or wolfram ...